# Reference another cell in a different row having calculated the minimum value in a datatable column

Tags: vb.net

[Reference another cell in the same row having calculated the minimum value in a datatable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65530312/reference-another-cell-in-the-same-row-having-calculated-the-minimum-value-in-a)

The above answered my question as to how to reference another cell in the **same** row having calculated the minimum value in a datatable column. But how do I reference a cell in another row still using that original cell?

In other words, if the min value in a column is in row 5, I now know how to get the values of cells in all other columns within row 5, but how do I get the values from columns within other rows (eg row 6) using the original cell as a starting point?

```
    Dim Data() As DataRow = datatable.Select("sourcecolumn = " & test.ToString())
    Dim column2 = Data(0)(1)
```

was the answer to my first question, how would I amend this to get to another row? I tried:

```
    dim column2 = Data(1)(1)
```

but it returns an array error. I think the numbers in brackets are absolute, but I need to use relative ones.

Thanks in advance again.

Comment: If "The above answered my question" why didn't you accept an answer. Future readers will think there was no solution.

Comment: Because I don’t spend much time on here and didn’t realise that’s what I had to do, I’ve done it now!

Comment: There's a bit of a problem in your thinking in the sense of "using the current row as a starting point" - we don't generally expect rows in a datatable to be in any particular position, so navigating around them using the notion of position relative to each other is somewhat meaningless. You found a cell in row 5, and a cell in row 6 has id 123 today, but it doesn't mean that tomorrow it will be the same. Instead find row 6 by some more concrete means (a lookup based on its own properties)

Comment: OK, understood, so having determined that "data" is the DataRow containing the lowest value in a certain column, how would I return the row number of "data"? I have tried "rowindex = datatable.Rows.IndexOf(data)" but I am now getting the error "Value of type 'DataRow()' cannot be converted to 'DataRow'"